# Script# For Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, script#

I am working with Script# with Visual Studio 2010. But now I need to develop an application and my development machine runs Windows XP with Visual Studio 2008.

Is there a place where I can download the last version (0.7.4) of Script# for Visual Studio 2008 ???

If there is no option to download 0.7.4 for Visal Studio 2008 is there a place to download the last version that supports Visual Studio 2008 ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to use .NET4 - that is a minimum requirement for the script# compiler. Assuming yes, the only thing specific to VS2010 (at the moment) is project templates. In the future, there will be more VS2010 dependencies and support, but for now, you can probably create your project in VS2010 and then tweak it to open in VS2008.

Alternatively, can you use Visual Web Developer Express 2010?

Unfortunately 2008 is no longer supported, and the last version that did that is really really old. Lots of changes have gone into the project since.